# Progress for LongPressureGesture on a Button

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, long-press

I got a button with a LongPressureGesture, and i would like to have a small ProgressView on top of this button as visual feedback for the user that the longPressureGesture is recognized.

I'm stuck on how to detect the beginning of the longPressure and the duration of the longPressure to be able to set the `setProgress()` on my ProgressView.

**EDIT:** So i inspired myself from the answers, thank you. Here is what i made. Feel free to comment the following code, maybe there is a better solution.

```
private var lpProgress:Float = 0
private var startTouch: NSTimer!

@IBAction func pauseJogButtonTouchDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.startTouch = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "updateLPGestureProgressView", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateLPGestureProgressView() {
    self.lpProgress += 0.1
    self.lpGestureProgressView.setProgress(self.lpProgress, animated: true)
    if self.lpProgress >= 1 {
        self.startTouch.invalidate()
        self.pauseBarButton.hidden = true
        self.lpGestureProgressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
        self.toolbarHomeMadeView.hidden = false
        self.switchToState(.Paused)
    }
}

@IBAction func pauseJogButtonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.lpProgress = 0
    self.startTouch.invalidate()
    self.lpGestureProgressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the LongPressureGesture in this case. 
Use "Touch Down" IBAction of UIButton to start NSTimer, and "Touch Up Inside" to stop timer and check if the delay was right.
ProgressView you can fill by timer progress.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an `NSTimer` on `touchesBegan`.

At the same time start your animation to animate the view.

When `touchesEnded` is triggered then stop the animation if the NSTimer has not triggered yet and cancel the timer.

When the timer finishes run your desired action.

Long Press isn't really designed for this sort of thing.